# jQuery slide effect issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

The idea was to have text appear when a user hovers over an image. That is working, but the slide effect isn't working. It appears abruptly and leave abruptly. I have both jQuery and jQuery-UI installed and no errors are coming up in the console. Any idea why?

HTML

```
 <div class="project-container">
              <a href"www.hiburnholidays.com"><img src="imgs/portfolio_hiburn.jpg"></a> 
              <div class="project-container__text">
               <p>
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat..
                </p>
              </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.project-container {
width: 38.4688rem;
height: 28.9rem;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
.project-container__text {
    padding: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    background: #63b9ce; 
    color: #fff;
}
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.project-container').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).find('.project-container__text').addClass('project-display'), function(){ //and one thing to be added you have to get the element in the given context of the selector with 'this keyword:
            $('.project-container__text').effect('slide', 'left');
        };
    });

    $('.project-container').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.project-container__text').removeClass('project-display'), function() {
            $('.project-container__text').effect('slide', 'right');
        };

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is addClass and removeClass don't actually accept a callback function. Try out something like this:

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('.project-container__text').addClass('project-display')
    $('.project-container__text').effect('slide', 'left');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.project-container__text').removeClass('project-display')
    $('.project-container__text').effect('slide', 'right');
  }
}, '.project-container');
```

Comment: Hi. It slides in, but it does what it did before, it glitches and slides in about 3 times before staying in its position

Comment: try using .on('mouseenter') instead of .on('mouseover')

Comment: still glitching, like it's repeating itself